# Display Gift Wrap on Product Detail page for EE 1.12

Tags: magento-enterprise

I've searched through the forum here but haven't found anything related to being able to display the built-in giftwrap module that comes with EE versions of Magento.

Has anyone tried doing this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this thread might address the issue that you are experiencing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736617/gift-wrap-is-not-showing-in-frontend

Comment: I did see that thread before posting here. Unfortunately this only deals with the checkout and does not address making the native Magento Giftwrap appear on the product detail page.